# Is it possible to have on the fly dynamic permissions for S3 upload?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've an iOS app and my users regularly upload pictures & videos. 
The number of users is dynamic, as there will be constant new users

Right now every time a user wants to upload a picture or video they have to connect to the `web-server`. The `web-server` will then go on and upload the file to the `S3 Bucket`.

I would like my users to be able to upload directly to a `S3 bucket` where they have their own directory.

To do that I need to create dynamic access rights so that my users are only allowed to upload & modify files in their directory lets say `/myBucket/USER-ID/*`

I know I can generate dynamic permissions with a token vending machine. But given that the  number of `users` is dynamic I do not know if it is possible for what I want to achieve.

I've tried researching on `TVM` but it seems that it cant cope with dynamic users? or at least I dont know how to send the current list of registered user that reside on a MongoDB.

Could anyone advice me if that is possible to do what I want and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is definitely possible. Depending on how your users are authenticating we have a couple of example solutions.

1. [Web identity federation](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/iOS/4617974389850313) which uses identities from Facebook, Google, and Amazon.  The sample mentioned in the linked article is a "S3 Personal Filestore" where each user gets a prefix in S3 they can write to.
2. A [Modified Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367) which also achieves the same goal using a java server backend and generating tokens.  The example TVM that we use does currently connect to a SimpleDB domain for storing user records, but should be possible to plug in an alternative datastore for "dynamic users".  The code for the server is available for modification to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank for the asnwer, could you point me to the tutorial that used the TVM using SimpleDB because I cant find it

Comment: The code download on the link I provided (http://aws.amazon.com/code/4598681430241367) uses SimpleDB, as well as the basic Identity TVM (http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566).

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't show how it pulls the usernames from simpledb or how to specify a table / row in simple db that could contain usernames

Comment: Unfortunately that is not documented as the focus of the walkthrough is the policies and the mobile application.  The source code is available (with javadoc for most classes) if you download the bundle.  You can look at the com.amazonaws.tvm.custom.UserAuthentication class for how users are loaded from SimpleDB and the com.amazonaws.tvm.TemporaryCredentialManagement class for how the policy is updated on a per user basis.